# How to install a torrent client on a NetBSD server with only SSH access

Tags: ssh, freebsd, bsd, bittorrent, netbsd

I have a remote server running NetBSD 6, to which I have access only via SSH. I have very limited Unix/Linux experience but I guess there are some command line torrent cliens available for Unixes like the ones in the BSD family.
Could someone help install a torrent client only using SSH access onto a NetBSD 6 server?

Thank you!

Comment: You can run X11 GUI applications over ssh. But command line or other remote controlled interface may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be `pkg_install transmission-cli`, Though I'd suggest upgrading from NetBSD 6, the current NetBSD release is 9.0